Space of all orthogonal partially complex $2\times2\times2$ tensors
I am trying to understand the space of all orthogonal tensors, I asked a more general version of this question here but with no solution yet found. I want to look at the simplest case first, namely a $2\times2\times2$ tensor.  This means if the $2\times2\times2$ tensor is denoted by $a_{i,j,k}$, then the following three equations must hold:
$$
\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{j=1}^2 a_{i,j,1} \overline{a}_{i,j,2} = 0
$$
$$\sum_{i=1}^2 \sum_{k=1}^2 a_{i,1,k} \overline{a}_{i,2,k} = 0
$$
$$\sum_{j=1}^2 \sum_{k=1}^2 a_{1,j,k} \overline{a}_{2,j,k} = 0
$$
Except this time instead of considering the most general case of the $2\times2\times2$ tensor being all complex, I want to consider a simpler version. That is where $a_{1,1,1}$, $a_{2,1,1}$, $a_{1,2,1}$, $a_{1,1,2}$ are positive reals and the rest of the entries are complex values. How can one characterize the space of solutions to these three equations? I do believe that the solution space should be 6 dimensional.

Why are you chosing only the values of $a_{1,1,1},a_{2,1,1},a_{1,2,1},a_{1,1,2}$ to be positive reals? And when you say dimensional, do you mean topological, algebraic, etc...?

@PedroJuanSoto I am investigating the space of unique core tensors in the HOSVD decomposition. I have concluded that requiring the values $a_{1,1,1}$, $a_{2,1,1}$, $a_{1,2,1}$ to be positive reals makes it somewhat unique. And by dimension I mean topological.
